Allocate two std::vectors after each other on memory in nested data structure
Let's say I have a data structure that looks something like this:
#include <vector>
#include <cstdef>

struct one {
    one(size_t n) : vec(n) {}
    std::vector<int> vec;
    // + some other stuff
};


struct entity {
    entity(size_t n) : One(n), Two(n) {}
    one One;
    one Two;
};

I want to have vec from Two allocated on memory right after vec from One ends, as it can make differences in performance. In C this would be easy by using pointer arrays. However I was wondering if there is a c++ style (using std::vectors) solution for that, maybe adapting the constructors?

std::vector does manage the dynamic memory of its elements. The vector itself is stored in one, the elements are stored elsewhere, if you want to control where you can use a custom allocator

I don't thing there is any such way. Size of vectors can be changed dynamically. What should happen in that case.

Not clear what is best without seeing the rest of your code. You could use a custom allocator but I think that's going to be messy and fragile. Sounds to me that the best solution is a vector allocated in Entity and then non-owning pointers to that vector in One and Two

If all you need is one contiguous array/vector, just create one array/vector instead of two.

Members of std::vector makes no alignment restirctions (24 per one struct, 28 per entity struct). You could use custom allocator to control elements in the vector itself

@user12002570 "Size of vectors can be changed dynamically. What should happen in that case" I understand the problem. Therefore I guess I need an other container. Anyone have suggestions for any other c++ container, that is similar to std::vector but with fixed size and is suited for my problem?

@PyOPTProblem, std::array is a thin wrapper around a plain fixed-size array. Apparently, it is stored the same way as a plain array would be. So I think it should suit your needs.

@RuslanOsmanov The Problem with std::array is that it's size have to be known at compile time, which not suits for my problem

You can use the span for this
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <ranges>
#include <span>

struct Part {
    Part(int *ptr, std::size_t n)
        : span(ptr, n)
    {
        std::ranges::fill(span, std::rand());
    }

    std::span<int> span;
};

struct Entity {
    Entity(std::size_t n)
        : mem(new int[n * 2]),
          first(mem.get(), n),
          second(mem.get() + n, n)
    {}

    std::unique_ptr<int[]> mem;
    Part first;
    Part second;
};

int main()
{
    Entity ent(10);
    const auto print = [](int a){ std::cout << a << std::endl; };
    std::ranges::for_each(ent.first.span, print);
    std::ranges::for_each(ent.second.span, print);
}

example in compiler explorer

You do not need a custom deleter for a unique_ptr<int[]>; it picks the array deleter automatically.

You may pre-allocate memory and only use std::span in one refering to the memory you use.
